# What does x: stand for in x:key and x:name ? Why the colon and why not y:?

Tags: wpf, xaml

This is confusing to me. Why do we have to use `x:Key=` and `x:Name=` in place of `key=` and `name=`?

Where does this `x` come from?

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider extracting the question about *directive* vs. *extension* into a separate SO question. As happening now, there are some good answers on the `x`-related question, but they do not answer the question about *directive* vs. *extension*. You will only be able to mark *one* answer as accepted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `'X'` is an alias for an imported namespace (See the declaration of your XAML).

`xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`

so when you type `x`, you use resources from that defined namespace. Actually, `Name` and `Key` are defined in the xaml namespace.

Comment: Simple, finally :) Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The name and key properties are defined within a namespace to avoid clashing with properties of the same name defined on the controls I believe.

Comment: Your answer complete Aphelion's answer... Thanks !